# Is it possible to show all the resources that are being taken over by a single process in android?

Tags: android

I use the activity manager in order to list all the processes. I can get the Pid and their name. That's fine.

Now my question is, what kind of information can I get about the resources that each of these processes uses?

I've tried getting some information about the memory from the MemoryInfo class but I find it difficult to understand the information that I get from calling some functions

but other than memory, what kind of information can I find?

is it possible for example to run a command that will give me a list with all the system resource usage for each process like for example in windows when we click on control+alt+delete?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Android's [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) tool, specifically viewing memory allocations and heap.

Comment: It helps only with debuggable applications.